# Does Web Audio have any plans of making limiters, imager, saturator, or multiband compressors?

Tags: web-audio-api

I have checked the interfaces that web audio offers. Pizzicato.js offers a great library for these effects, but it is a pitty that some of the best and essential effects are missing, like a limiter, multi-band compressor, parametric equalizer, saturator, stereo imager. I was just wondering if there any plans for them where i can check if they are willing to make these in the future. Just don't know where i could ask.

Thanks

Comment: I think the idea is for Web Audio API to have the most basic audio processing nodes, and from those, you can build more and interesting things. So you may not have a built-in 3 band EQ, or an 11 band EQ, but you do have the tools to make them.

Answer (score 2):

WebAudio is a collection of fairly elemental base processors. There's really no  higher order effects, because instead, it provides the foundational elements with which to build the effects.

For example, there's a dynamics compressor, but there's no variMU emulation, or FET circuit, or even your run of the mill digital compressor. But, using the pieces that the API does have, you can build out or model a compressor that behaves however you want. Just think it through and figure out how the signal needs to be processed and you'll find pretty much every component you need to achieve it. If not, the AudioWorklet(the successor to the deprecated ScriptProcessorNode) can fill in the blanks.

That being said, you would build a limiter using the DynamicsCompressor, and use BiquadFilters and DynamicsCompressors to build a multiband comp. You'd use the WaveShaper to build things like tape saturators, overdrive, and bit crushers. And you can create an imager or stereo widener effect using things like the PannerNode and one of the AudioParams (setValueAtTime() is probably the simplest).

WebAudio isn't really plug & play, but it's what you'd use to build something that is. If you'd rather skip the tedium of building your own DSPs, I can't really blame you, it's not easy. But there's plenty of sadists out there who already did, and many are made by very imaginative and talented engineers. A couple libraries worth checking out would be Tuna.js which is a very user friendly/straight forward effects library, or Tone.js for something much more fleshed out and complete.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs several already seem to be implemented:

- Compressor: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DynamicsCompressorNode
- EQ: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BiquadFilterNode
- Saturator can probaby be impemented using: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ConvolverNode

Comment: Thank you. How about stereo imager? with stereo panning only pans directional ways towards left or right, but doesn't apply widening or narrowing audio signals. Or is it still possible to apply with this interface?

Comment: I'm not familiar with a 'stereo imager' so I don't know what exactly it does but if you had a click through the documentation I linked you might have seen this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PannerNode 
sounds like this could be what you are describing. I would also encourage you to click through documentation and look at even functions that seem unrelated! You can discover many useful things fast. For example the answer on top was the result of me first time looking at the Web Audio API docs for the first time...